Create multiple SharePoint list items from a single entry form (repetitive items)
I have a project where I need to track a document development process, sometimes different tasks are assigned to a single person, and multiple reviewers
The idea is for the form to capture all the information needed, but only having to type the repetitive items once, such as date, subject, task number, but assigned to different people.

Store the document in the document library, and make sure that you open the document and turn on version tracking (redlining) in the document itself.  Encourage users to comment within the document as well for a better review experience.  SharePoint provides you with default columns in a document library.  Expose all of those in your document library view so you can see created by, modified by, etc.  Also, make sure that only major (not minor) versions are being tracked.  This assures that one person's changes don't get overwritten by a major version.  Next, create a column for task that describes what those individuals assigned to that task need to do. As each person does their task, Sharepoint will update the version history for that same document with the date and time that user made changes.  You can optionally create columns (and even views) for your approvers.  I use their initials for the column name, and I make it a "Y/N" column so they can just click on it to approve.  You can further create a view for each approver so that they can scroll to their view, see the ones that aren't checked, review them, and check them.  This is one of my favorite designs and works for all kinds of approval workflows.

Thank you for the input, what I am actually looking for is to create a form to keep track of the development of the document not so much the changes on the document. Something like a parent/child (one to many relationship) that would capture the same date, same issuing party, same document type, and then the child(s) will capture who is assigned to, the topic(s) etc. and when click on SAVE, the form will then create a single sharepoint list item for each child, with the same parent information.
